# In Ubuntu WSL, how can you store permanent environment variables?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've tried but every time I restart my system my variables are gone.

How can I store my environment variables in a permanent way on Ubuntu WSL2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environments in `~/.profile` works for me.

This file is not read by bash(1), if `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`
exists.

Works on WSL2 Ubuntu.

Comment: On other platforms there can be reasons to prefer `.profile` for some things (in particular, it is read by other shells than Bash) but for WSL, you should probably simply use `.bash_profile` instead.

Answer (score 16):

So this is the way that worked for me:

`~/.bash_profile` is the correct file for permanent environment variables if using Bash on Ubuntu WSL2, however make sure you add the `export` keyword before your variables, like so:

```
export THISVAR=thisIsAVar
export ANOTHERVAR=anotherVar
```

To add the variable(s) use the command `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` (if you prefer Nano editor) or `sudo vim ~/.bash_profile` (if you prefer Vim). After you have entered your variables into the `.bash_profile` save the file and then enter `source ~/.bash_profile` to have the variables available in the terminal.

Comment: This is a non-working solution on my machine.  There must be some kind of group policy getting in the way?  Debian buster on WSL2.

Comment: Agree that your solution should always have been the accepted answer.  Not quite sure why you ever changed it to mine (other than someone's comment suggesting it)!  I'm glad you fixed that!

Comment: This was discussed [in the WSL issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4359). @Nomnom Are you the author of [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4359#issuecomment-743420973)?

Comment: @DouglasSilva yes that was me. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Nomnom Nothing. I'm just linking the information for future readers.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish a variable to persist after you close the shell session, you need to set it as an environmental variable permanently. You can choose between setting it for the current user or all users.

1. To set permanent environment variables for a single user, edit the .bashrc file:

   sudo nano ~/.bashrc
2. Write a line for each variable you wish to add using the following syntax:

   export [VARIABLE_NAME]=[variable_value]
3. now restart your terminal

this is a full link for it:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-set-environment-variable

Comment: `.bashrc` will not be read by your login shell unless you specifically set up `.bash_profile` to also source `.bashrc`. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this.

1. First, and the normal method (as you've discovered), is by setting the environment variables in your shell startup scripts.  For bash, this would be `~/.bash_profile`, for zsh it would be `~/.zprofile`, and for fish it would be `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.
2. But let me also suggest that you consider trying out the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com), as it has a great feature in its ability to set "universal variables", which are automatically propagated to all other instances of the shell, both present and in the future.

   E.g. `set -Ux myvariable 42` will create a universal (and exported) variable that will persist even after you close and reopen the shell, without having to create config files.

   Fish has a number of other great features that make it my go-to shell (after 15 years on zsh).

That said, I'm not sure what your goal is with WSL, but if it's to "learn Linux", then you might be better off starting with bash or zsh since they are more "traditional" shells, with bash, of course, being the defacto starndard.

Comment: I was using environment variables to store secrets, so that I don't have to include plain text secrets in my code. I find it strange that environment variables are attached to shells directly, i thought they were more related to the OS directly and shell agnostic.

Comment: Well, you are correct - Environment variables *are* an OS construct, and each process has its own  environment that is set when the process is launched.  But since the shell is usually responsible for launching subprocesses (especially in WSL), that's usually where the variables are managed.  It's *possible* (but not common) to set them in other Linux environments (not WSL) for the kernel, which would then, I believe, propagate them to all processes.

Comment: Mark this as the answer OP

Answer (score 1):

add alias to `.bashrc` file

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

add this line end of the file (in my case I want to run laravel)

```
alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/bin/laravel'
```

then restart wsl shell

```
exit
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The OP question was how to set *environment variables*.  Those aren't the same as *aliases*, which is what your answer covers.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `zsh` on wsl, so changing `~/.bashrc` file didn't work.

Exporting PATH from `~/.zshrc` did the trick.

I added this line at the end of `~/.zshrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin
```

Then restarted the wsl shell.